# Use of 'reflect' in this context

Tags: verbs, word-in-context

I read these lines somewhere a few days ago. I don't have the source, sorry.

> "I edited the About section but it does not reflect on the website."

It means the website does not show the changes made, it does not show the updated information. That's how I interpret it. Please correct me if it means something else

I have never seen the word reflect used like this before. I know we use reflect to show or express something indirectly. By indirectly, I mean it is obvious if I pay attention. As in,

> "The way he admires her reflects his love for her."

> "The latest report reflects a change in public opinion about...'

Back to the original sentence, is it correct to use reflect that way and can someone explain why it has been used that way?
Thank you

Comment: I think you answered your question pretty well. It could mean that It didn't get updated
and it could mean -which is also true- that "the changes he made to website, didn't improve his website"

Comment: @Atrin Noori I know for a fact that it was not their website, and the changes there were trying to make was related to their personal info. It did not have anything to do with improving the website. What you are suggesting is, we can use 'reflect' this way? If we want to convey the meaning that the website did not show the updated information? I mean, it's a bit direct isn't it? As I have mentioned in my post, reflect is often used to show or express something indirectly, something that is not completely obvious until we pay attention

Comment: Your interpretation is correct, although I personally wouldn't use *reflect* that way; I would say "the change **was not reflected** on the website."  But a lot of people do use *reflect* in that active way.

Comment: @stangdon I am not sure if you understood my question well, or if I was able to put it across well. What I am asking is, if I edit my saved personal info on a website and it still does not show the updated details that I put in, after I hit 'save', I want to say that the website's still not showing the changes I made to my personal info. Can I use the verb reflect in this context and say, "I edited my About section but the website does not reflect that." ?? Thank you

Comment: I said it is _**also**_ OK if it is used in this way